# VSCode SSH remote friendly host name

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I have this `.config` file for SSH hosts:

```
Host 10.32.1.43
  HostName 10.32.1.43
  User root
  ForwardAgent yes
Host 10.32.0.39
  HostName 10.32.0.39
  User administrator
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Can I give more friendly names to my machines, instead of remembering which of them is the **Ubuntu** machine, and which is the **CentOS**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you change the Host line it changes the name displayed in VSCode and normal ssh commands

```
Host example
   HostName myexampleip.local
   User example
```

using this example config file can be used with this command
`ssh example`

**NOTE** (as mnagel has commented)

The user-friendly name goes **behind "Host"** and the IP/hostname to connect to goes behind "Hostname".

Comment: this is basically right albeit i don't find the example very well-picked. the user-friendly name goes behind "Host" and the IP/hostname to connect to goes behind "Hostname".